# Convert jpg to picamera.array.PiRGBArray

Tags: python, jpeg

I wish to, inside a python3 program.py, convert jpg images (already on my computer) into a picamera.array.PiRGBArray ?

I tried asking this on the RaspberryPi but could not.
I’ve tried searching google, and reading the docs at picamera.

My program works, except for not being able to convert the jpg.

Here is the program so far,

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import cv2

#the image to convert
img0= "./images/g/g1.jpg"

camera = PiCamera()
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(512, 304))

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
    #convertedJpeg =  (how to convert img0 to type <class 'picamera.array.PiRGBArray'>) 

    # do stuff with image and convertedJpg
    # do other stuff
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: maybe find out what format the camera.capture_continuous() method is expecting (seems to have something to do with 'rawCapture' and 'bgr'), and convert the JPEGs yourself to whatever format that is using some other program ?

Answer (score 0):

The code which solved my problem was,

```
convertedJpg = cv2.imread('/path/to/file.jpg')
```

As it turns out, what I really needed was to, 
"convert the jpg to numpy.ndarray".

Now you can do,

```
covertedJpg.shape
```

and,

```
image.shape  #from the code posted
```

and notice they both have the same shape.  Now you can do stuff with them.